# C# Get a List of StartDate and EndDate of all the Weeks Between two given dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Model Class named `DurationModel` which looks like below.

```
public class DurationModel
{       
    public DateTime DurationStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime DurationEndDate { get; set; }
}
```

I want to populate a list of this Class Objects by supplying two `DateTime` variables like the below.

```
List<DurationModel> DurationList = GetDurationList(StartDate, EndDate);
```

Following are the conditions:

- Each Duration object will contain one week, Starting on Mondays and Ending on Sundays.
- For the edge elements (first and last element of the list) the `DurationStartDate` will be the `StartDate` and `DurationEndDate` will be the `EndDate` respectively for that segment.

**Example:** If my `StartDate = 25-Dec-2019` and `EndDate = 16-Jan-2020` then the List would look something like this when populated:

```
{25-Dec-2019, 29-Dec-2019} // Segment starts from StartDate, ends on Sunday
{30-Dec-2019, 5-Jan-2020}  // Segment starts from Monday, Ends on Sunday
{6-Jan-2020, 12-Jan-2020}  // Segment starts from Monday, Ends on Sunday
{13-Jan-2020, 16-Jan-2020} // Segment starts from Monday, Ends on EndDate
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Even if you cover a few years span, that would amount to 52 * number of years. Small numbers for computers, so you can build the list element by element with no noticeable performance impact, IMHO.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.datetime.dayofweek?view=netframework-4.8 would help you find the current day of the week and reach next Monday then +7 until the end of duration

Comment: Can you not just loop through whatever list it is and return where `startDate <= i && endDate > i`

Comment: I tried something like the answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error I came up with this. Positing this as an answer in case it comes to someone else's use.

```
    private List<DurationModel> GetDurationList(DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate)
    {
        List<DurationModel> DurationList = new List<DurationModel>();

        // Start from Start Date, get Next Sunday.
        DateTime FirstSundayAfterStartDate = StartDate.AddDays(7 - (int)StartDate.DayOfWeek);

        // Add First Segment
        DurationList.Add(new DurationModel(StartDate, FirstSundayAfterStartDate));

        DateTime NextMonday = FirstSundayAfterStartDate.AddDays(1);
        DateTime NextSunday = FirstSundayAfterStartDate.AddDays(7);

        // Add intermediate segments
        while (NextSunday <= EndDate)
        {
            DurationList.Add(new DurationModel(NextMonday, NextSunday));

            NextMonday = NextSunday.AddDays(1);
            NextSunday = NextSunday.AddDays(7);
        }

        // Add Last Segment
        DurationList.Add(new DurationModel(NextMonday, EndDate));

        return DurationList;
    }
```

Comment: Good for you! Days of the week is pretty useful, right?